# Steam doesn't start in Debian. It lacks 32-bit libGL.so.1

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia-graphics-card, steam

I use Debian sid, with the proprietary NVIDIA driver, version 325.15.

Whenever I start Steam, it says I don't have 32-bit libraries.

I've seen lots of "fixes" to this problem, but every one of them involves apt-getting the lib files, and I can't do that, because their version doesn't match with the driver version.

I've used Steam with those drivers before, but I don't quite remember how I got it to work.

Comment: Keep trying the "fixes"

Comment: I can't, installing the missing libs would also install the old drivers, but I already have the new ones installed.

Comment: Install the old ones?

Comment: I've used the new ones before, and they are a huge improvement in speed. I just need to know where are the 32-bit libraries so I can't symlink them to the steam folder, and it'll probably. I don't know where are those libs though.

Comment: Get it working then get it optimized....

Comment: I fixed it; turns out sgfxi doesn't install the 32-bit libraries, so I just downloaded and ran the driver installer from the NVIDIA website, and edited my /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf to include /emul/ia32-linux/usr/lib.

Comment: Post your answer in the answer section

Comment: I'll have to wait 6 hours, but OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

Turns out sgfxi doesn't install the 32-bit libraries, so I just downloaded and ran the driver installer from the NVIDIA website, and edited my /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf to include /emul/ia32-linux/usr/lib.

DKMS will not work, but that is probably because I'm using the Liquorix kernel.